# Is there ever a clear explanation of why Rivka wears a mask over her face?

Tags: shira-glassman, mangoverse

In Shira Glassman's Mangoverse novels, Rivka/Captain Riv is a woman pretending to be a man in order to work as a guard for the Queen (and later becomes Captain of the guards). It's noted that she wears a mask over the lower part of her face.

There is a lot of mention of the reasons other people think she's wearing it (usually because they assume, due to the many tales of her exploits, that it is due to some great disfiguring injury or the like), but I can't really recall a mention explicitly in the books that states her actual reasoning. I assume it's to help hide her feminine features, but do any of the books (*The Second Mango, Climbing the Date Palm, A Harvest of Ripe Figs,* or *The Olive Conspiracy*) or the short story collection (*Tales from Perach*, which I have not read yet) actually state why she does this?